# nested loops through a structured list in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, data.table

I have an example dataset, `garden`, as shown below. The real thing is thousands of rows. I also have an example list. `productFruit`. I  want to know the `calories` of every `fruit`, considering the `usage` reported in `garden`. I basically want to loop through all the rows in my table, check if the usage is `recorded` in the `productFruit` list and the return either the `calories` or one of the following error messages:

- "usage out of scope" if no `usage` has been found in the `productFruit` list
- "fruit out of scope" if no `usage` has been found in the `productFruit` list
- "erroneous data" if data is missing

`garden`:

```
fruit = c("Apple", "Kiwi", "Banana", "Orange", "Blueberry")
usage = c("cooking", "cooking", "NA", "drinking", "medicine")
reported = c(200, 500, 77, 520, 303)

    garden <- cbind(fruit, usage, reported)
    garden <- as.data.table(garden)
```

`productFruit`:

```
productFruit <- list(Basket = c('DUH'), 
                type = list (
                  Apple = list(ID = 1,
                            color = "poor",
                            usage = list(eating = list(ID = 1,
                                                       quality = "good",
                                                       calories = 500),
                                         medicine = list(ID = 2,
                                                         quality = "poor",
                                                         calories = 300))),
                  Orange = list(ID = c(1,2,3),
                            color = c(3,4,5),
                            usage = list(eating = list(ID = 1,
                                                       quality = "poor",
                                                       calories = 420),
                                         cooking = list(ID = 2,
                                                        quality = "questionable",
                                                        calories = 600),
                                         drinking = list(ID = 3,
                                                         quality = "good",
                                                         calories = 800),
                                         medicine = list(ID = 4,
                                                         quality = "good",
                                                         calories = 0))),
                  Banana = list(ID = c(1,2,3),
                           color = c(3,4,5),
                           usage = list(cooking = list(ID = 1,
                                                      quality = "good",
                                                      calories = 49),
                                          drinking = list(ID = 2,
                                                          quality = "questionable",
                                                          calories = 11),
                                          medicine = list(ID = 3,
                                                          quality = "poor",
                                                          calories = 55)))))
```

I tried to break it down into smaller steps and doing this with loops, but i have very little experience with `lists` and was getting many errors. Any ideas how to solve this in an efficient & readable way? Below one of my many attempts to just match the `fruits`. I am aware that the field do not match, i was just trying to get the loop to run at all...

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(garden))){
  if (garden$fruit[i] == productFruit$type){
    garden$calories = productFruit$type[[i]]$ID
  } 
  garden$calories = "error"
}
```

The desired output is this:

```
    fruit = c("Apple", "Kiwi", "Banana", "Orange", "Blueberry")
    usage = c("cooking", "cooking", "NA", "drinking", "medicine")
    reported = c(200, 500, 77, 520, 303)
    calories = c("usage out of scope", "fruit out of scope", "erroneous data", 800, "fruit out of scope")

garden_with_calories <- cbind(fruit, usage, reported, calories)
garden_with_calories <- as.data.table(garden)
```

Comment: You have the data available as the `garden` `dataframe` or as the `productFruit` `list`? Or both?

Comment: I've significantly simplified my answer. I'd be curious how it performs against the other posted solutions.

Answer (score 1):

## Update

For large dataset, `for` loop is not recommended. Following codes are the alternative

**Step 1 check if fruit exist on product list**

```
fruitExist <- fruit %in% names(productFruit$type)
```

**Step 2 for every fruit, check if corresponding usage is exist on product list**

```
usageExist <- sapply(fruit, function(f){
  sapply(usage, `%in%`, x = names(productFruit$type[[f]][["usage"]]))})
usageExist <- as.data.frame(unique(sapply(usageExist[sapply(usageExist, is.logical)], colSums)))
usageExist$usage <- row.names(usageExist)
```

**Step 3 extract calories**

```
calories <-  data.frame(unique(
                  sapply(fruit, function(f){
                    sapply(usage, function(u){productFruit$type[[f]][["usage"]][[u]][["calories"]]})}
                    )))

calories <- unlist(as.data.frame(unique(
  sapply(fruit, function(f){
    sapply(usage, function(u){productFruit$type[[f]][["usage"]][[u]][["calories"]]})}
  ))))

calories <- as.data.frame(calories)
names(calories) <- "cal"
calories$fruitUsage <- row.names(calories)
```

**Step 4 combine and finalize**

```
library(tidyverse) 

garden %>%
  mutate(fruitExist = fruitExist) %>%
  left_join(usageExist %>% pivot_longer(-usage, names_to = "fruit", values_to = "usageExist")) %>%
  left_join(calories %>% separate(fruitUsage, c("fruit","usage"))) %>%
  mutate(calories = case_when(
    fruit == "NA" | usage == "NA" ~ "erroneous data",
    usageExist == FALSE ~ "usage out of scope",
    fruitExist == FALSE ~ "fruit out of scope",
    TRUE ~ as.character(cal))) %>%
  select(fruit, usage, reported, calories)
```

**Output**

```
garden

#       fruit    usage reported           calories
# 1     Apple  cooking      200 usage out of scope
# 2      Kiwi  cooking      500 fruit out of scope
# 3    Banana       NA       77     erroneous data
# 4    Orange drinking      520                800
# 5 Blueberry medicine      303 fruit out of scope
```

---

**Previus codes**

Try this:

```
cal <- as.character()

for(i in 1:length(fruit)){
  fruitName <- fruit[i]
  usageName <- usage[i]

  if(fruitName == "NA" | usageName == "NA") {
    out <- "erroneous data"
  } else if(!(fruitName %in% names(productFruit[["type"]]))){
    out <- "fruit out of scope"
  } else if(!(usageName %in% names(productFruit[["type"]][[fruitName]][["usage"]]))){
    out <- "usage out of scope"
  } else {
    out <- productFruit[["type"]][[fruitName]][["usage"]][[usageName]][["calories"]]
  }

  cal <- c(cal, out)
}

garden$calories <- cal
```

```
garden

#        fruit    usage reported           calories
# 1:     Apple  cooking      200 usage out of scope
# 2:      Kiwi  cooking      500 fruit out of scope
# 3:    Banana       NA       77     erroneous data
# 4:    Orange drinking      520                800
# 5: Blueberry medicine      303 fruit out of scope
```

Comment: very nice and working solution. However, it does take some time to run this. Can this be somehow speeded up? my actual data for fruit and usage are actually factors that i converted to characters. Would leaving them in thee factor format speed it up?

Comment: @Danka in R, for large dataset, it is not recommended to use `for` loop. I have updated my answer using another approach

Comment: I managed to run it with 5000 observations, whereby the list already has 580.9MB...

Comment: unfortunately your edited solution doesnt run when there is a large number of observations. I managed to run it for 10 with no problem, also 1000 was fine, but every time i run it with the whole data (64 000+) observations, R gets stuck ...I managed to run it with 5 000 observations, whereby the list already has 580.9MB... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Extracting data from nested lists can be very tedious. Here is some code that works for the example you provided, but might still struggle, in case you have entries that vary from the example data. You'll probably have to make it more robust and check that the data has the `class` you expect it to be etc.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

## Step 1:

We create a some code that extracts one fruit at a time:

```
# this creates a tibble with a column for each usage entry (eating, drinking,
# etc.)
type_df <- as.tibble(productFruit$type[[1]]$usage)

# With map*() we apply as.tibble() to each column to get a one-row data frame
# per "usage" case. We use map_dfr() in order to bind togeter the resulting
# rows into one dataframe. This is the line that might need to be made more
# robust in order to not fail on unexpected input.)
res <- map_dfr(type_df, as.tibble, .id = "usage")

# When there is no usage entry, `res` will be empty and we create a dummy
# dataframe for that case that has `NA` for the "colories" column.
if (nrow(res) < 1)
  tibble(calories = NA)
else
  res
```

## Step 2:

Now we put the previous lines into a function, so we can apply it to all fruits.

```
extract_fruit_data <-
  function(fruit) {
    type_df <- as.tibble(fruit$usage)
    res <- map_dfr(type_df, as.tibble, .id = "usage")
    if (nrow(res) < 1)
      tibble(calories = NA)
    else
      res
  }
```

## Step 3:

We apply `extract_fruit_data` to each fruit's entry and bind togther the
resulting rows using `map_dfr()`. Then we drop and rename some of the variables,
in preparation for the next step.

```
fruits_df <-
  map_dfr(productFruit$type, extract_fruit_data, .id = "type") %>%
  select(-ID, -quality) %>% 
  rename(fruit = type)
```

## Step 4:

We join the two datasets with `left_join()` that way each entry in garden,
is kept and those entries that are not matched in fruits_df gets an `NA`
in the calories column. With `case_when()` we classify each column,
according to your specifications

```
left_join(garden, fruits_df) %>% 
  mutate(calories = case_when(
    usage == "NA" ~ "erroneous data",
    !fruit %in% fruits_df$fruit ~ "fruit out of scope",
    is.na(calories) ~ "usage out of scope",
    TRUE ~ as.character(calories)
  ))
```

Comment: could you break it down, or explain what is happening in the steps? How efficient do you think is approach is in terms of time ? My data has 7000 rows and the list of around 3000 Fruits

Comment: I updated my answer to explain the steps better. I think for the size of your data this should be rather quick. In case it is to slow or you could use the `furrr` package, which is a parallelized version of `purrr`. All you'd have to do for this is, change the `map_dfr()` in Step 4 to `future_map_dfr()` and put a `plan(multisession)` in front of that command. The code will then be executed on all available CPU cores.

Comment: i tried to implement your solution and then realised that your code actually never uses the dataset garden ? It doesnt link the data anywhere, it only uses the list.

Comment: I re-read your simplified question and made according changes to my answer. Steps 3 is slightly modified, step 4 is completely different now.

Answer (score 1):

I made this code in `Base R` that finds and reports only the fruits and their respective usage that are actually present. I know its not exactly what you asked for but by the time I realised that it was a bit too late. Its a very different approach to other proposed solutions.

```
FruitNames <- unlist(lapply(productFruit,names)[2])

UsageByFruit <- lapply(FruitNames, function(X) names(productFruit[["type"]][[X]][["usage"]]))
LengthByFruit<- lapply(UsageByFruit, length)

gardenlength <- sum(unlist(LengthByFruit))
garden <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=3,nrow=gardenlength, dimnames=list(NULL, c("Fruit", "Usage", "Calories"))))

garden[,2] <- unlist(UsageByFruit)
garden[,1] <- unlist(lapply(1:length(FruitNames), function(X) replicate(LengthByFruit[[X]],FruitNames[X])))
garden[,3] <- unlist(lapply(1:length(FruitNames), function(X) unlist(lapply(unlist(UsageByFruit[X]), function(Y) productFruit[["type"]][[FruitNames[X]]][["usage"]][[Y]][["calories"]]  ))))
```

Output:

```
> garden
   Fruit    Usage Calories
1  Apple   eating      500
2  Apple medicine      300
3 Orange   eating      420
4 Orange  cooking      600
5 Orange drinking      800
6 Orange medicine        0
7 Banana  cooking       49
8 Banana drinking       11
9 Banana medicine       55
```

Comment: this is a great & readable solution. the only downside is that iI actually need all the fruits, incl those where the usage is actually NOT present in the list.... but i am sure i will find great usage of this approach in other parts of my project. Very appreciated